# Trouble compiling tailwindcss on AWS Beanstalk with Rails 5.1

Tags: amazon-web-services, webpack, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, tailwind-css

I did have this working, so have obviously messed something up but can't spot what.

I'm trying to deploy to AWS beanstalk but I get the following error in the logs:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--1-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??ref--1-3!./app/javascript/css/application.css
      Module build failed: Error: Loading PostCSS Plugin failed: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss'
```

I am using Webpack to compile tailwind. Nodejs & Yarn are installed ok.

**app/javascript/packs/application.js**

```
import '../css/application.css';
```

**app/javascript/css/application.css & app/javascript/css/tailwind.js**

both contain the code listed at https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration

**.postcssrc.yml**

```
plugins:
  postcss-import: {}
  tailwindcss: 'app/javascript/css/tailwind.js'
  postcss-cssnext: {}
```

I had resolved a previous webpack issue by running `NODE_ENV=production webpack` prior to `eb deploy`.  Have tried this again, but no dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by:

> Moved tailwaindcss to dependencies instead of devDependencies in
>   package.json